# Send cross-domain HTTP-POST from google docs

Tags: javascript, http-post, google-docs-api, google-sheets-api

I need to pass the POST request from the google docs by google scripts on the other site. The request must be transmitted whenever there is a change in the cell. The request shall contain the information from the different cells. I created the link but I can not send it.

```js
function onEdit(e){
  // Set a comment on the edited cell to indicate when it was changed.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var range = e.range;
  // var to sent
  var wait = 'wait'; // status
  var approve = 'approve'; // status
  var decline = 'decline'; // status
  var amount = 990; // price
  var sec = 'a1atugqv'; // ID to server
  var vcode = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 9).getValue(); // ID clients` click
  var orderID = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 2).getValue(); // ID order
  // end
  var listItem = e.value; // Value drop-down cell, wich edit
  //var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); I tried using this transfer. It did not work
  var url = 'http://example.com/common.php?vcode=' + vcode + '&amount=' + amount + '&order_id=' + orderID + '&sec=' + sec + '&status=';
  if ((listItem == 'new') || (listItem == 'mobile off') || (listItem == 'send')){
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://www.example.com/'); // I tried using this transfer. It did not work
    // i should send POST or GET here. With new status
    //var site = url + wait;
    //var resData = UrlFetchApp.fetch(site);
  } else if ((listItem == 'approve') || (listItem == 'send') || (listItem == 'ok')){
    // i should send POST or GET here. With new status
    range.setNote('approve'); // check
    //xhr.open('GET', url + approve, true);
    // xhr.send();
  } else if ((listItem == 'decline') || (listItem == 'return')){
    range.setNote('decline');
    //xhr.open('GET', url + decline, true);
    // xhr.send();
  }
}
```

Comment: solved a problem.
Has earned this construction when sending

    var site = url + wait;
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(site);

Comment: now its not working :(

Comment: now its working. But i do nothing...

Comment: Have you heard of Postman? My work flow usually starts out by checking my requests are working in Postman, before using going to Apps script. Postman is a free add-on to chrome.